# Iframe incorporado de outro site - 100% da tela

Tags: iframe

Me passaram um código para incorporar no meu site, mas ele gera um iframe e não ocupa 100% da tela.

```css
#areaCondominio {
 
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 h1: blue;
}
#testenov {
 width: 100%;
 background: orange;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>

<script src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/widgets.superlogica.net/embed.js" ></script>




</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="10">
<div id="testenov"><h2>oooooooooo</h2
  <script type="text/javascript">
/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/
superlogica.require("condominios");
superlogica.condominios("areadocondomino","areaCondominio","vgm","1");
/*]]>{/literal}*/
</script>
<div id="areaCondominio"><h1>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1></div>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Voçe pode ultilizar o 'overflow: auto' como no exemplo abaixo ele abrira uma barra scroll aonde lhe mostrara todo o texto introduzido ou se preferir com 'overflow-wrap: break-word' voce tera quebra de linha.

```css
#areaCondominio {
 
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
}
#testenov {
 width: 100%;
 background: orange;
 
}

   h1 {
 color: blue;
        overflow: auto;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>

<script src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/widgets.superlogica.net/embed.js" ></script>




</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="10">
<div id="testenov"><h2>oooooooooo</h2
  <script type="text/javascript">
/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/
superlogica.require("condominios");
superlogica.condominios("areadocondomino","areaCondominio","vgm","1");
/*]]>{/literal}*/
</script>
<div id="areaCondominio"><h1>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1></div>

</div>
```